# Confusion with swift file

Tags: ios, swift

In `Objective C`, there is 2 files `.h and .m`....

for example in .h file, i give `UIAlertview` method name like below...

```
-(void)showAlertForTitle:(NSString *)strTitle withMessage:(NSString *)strMessage;
```

and in `.m` file, i give its implementation like below....

```
- (void)showAlertForTitle:(NSString *)strTitle withMessage:(NSString *)strMessage
{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:strTitle message:strMessage delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
}
```

and whenever i want to call it i just doing like

```
[self showAlertForTitle:@"title" withMessage:@"msg"];
```

**Problem:**
so my question is....as there is only one swift file `.swift` is available in swift...does i need to give all implementation in `.swift` file and just import file and make a call of a method or other way to doing it so.....

Comment: You need to read the Swift book from available.  It's available for free from the iBook store.

Comment: A few points for you the Bhavin.  First, questions should be down voted if they're not clearly written or otherwise don't meet the criteria of a good question.  Second, I didn't down vote or vote to close the question.  Third, I did understand the question, that's why I recommended you read the available literature as it's obvious you haven't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In swift you don't need to do it this way just declare function this way into your swift file:

```
func showAlertForTitle(strTitle: String, withMessage strMessage: String) {

}
```

and you can call it this way:

```
showAlertForTitle("title", withMessage: "msg")
```

**EDIT :**

And your alert function will be something like this:

```
func showAlertForTitle(strTitle: String, withMessage strMessage: String) {

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: strTitle, message: strMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And If you want to access it into another file you can do it this way:

**Global.swift**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

func showAlertForTitle(strTitle: String, withMessage strMessage: String) {

   let myAlert = UIAlertView()
   myAlert.title = strTitle
   myAlert.message = strMessage
   myAlert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
   myAlert.show()
}
```

Now you can show alert anywhere in your project with this function.